# Having issue with a selector

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The code is simple but I having trouble figuring out the selector

```
import csv
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://website.com').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

nextpage= soup.find("a", string="3").get('href')
print (nextpage)
```

gives me the href associated with 3... but when I try `"Next"` I am getting None error

the path is:

```
<a class="" href="https://website.com;page=2">Next ›</a>]
```

what am I doing wrong? is there another way to select the selector for next...

the code (below) works

```
nextpage= main_pagination.find_all('a', class_='')[3]
```

BUT the problem with that code is that next could be [5] on another search... I need a universal solution for this page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,utils
html = '<a class="" href="https://website.com;page=2">Next ›</a>'
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
nextpage = doc.getElementByReg('Next',tag='a')
print(nextpage)
```

Result:

```
{'class': '', 'href': 'https://website.com;page=2', 'tag': 'a', 'html': 'Next ›'}
```

Here are more examples. https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples

Comment: its working I can get both href and text "Next" from this. HOWEVER I am reluctant to use it. b/c I am not using simplified-scrapy I am using BS4 and this is only a small part of a larger code built using bs4. I could do both simplifiedDoc AND bs4.`source = requests.get('https://mainpage.com').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

doc = SimplifiedDoc(source)

nextpage = doc.getElementByReg('Next',tag='a')
nextlink= nextpage.get('href')
print(nextlink)` but what would the implications of that be? I just don't get why your code is working while mine with just bs4 isnt working?

Comment: @blake Sorry, I'm not familiar with BS4. getElementByReg looks up element through regex.

Comment: Thank you! I figured out how to do this thanks to your hint! I just used regular expression for BS4 (re.compile) and got it to work!